# Opensource Project Management software

Tags: c#, project-management

Can someone guide me towards some good opensource project management tools?

I need it for managing projects for a development team. All developers are c# developers.

What would be the best one to go for?

We're not familiar with php or any other language so we prefer something in .Net or some software that's more easy to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia has a good comparison chart...unfortunately, the .NET pickings are extremely slim:

[Comparison of project management software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_project_management_software)

Looks like the most full-featured Open Source ones out there are Java based. It goes down from there. The only .NET Project Management software I've seen was SharpForge (which has since gotten sucked in to a commercial product).

Comment: Project-Open sounds like a good choice :)

Answer (score 2):

Trac (http://trac.edgewall.org/) is one of most used, even if not written in .NET.

Answer (score 2):

Seriously. i love [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/). It's a project management application written in Ruby. It's very easy to install through the installation package. I highly recommend it.

It works great on a windows platform.